# issues in integrating Spotify SDK on Flutter for iOS

Tags: flutter, configuration, spotify, spotify-app

I have implemented the Spotify SDK, which is working successfully on Flutter for Android. However, I am facing issues with the configuration on iOS.

I am not receiving the access token. This might be due to some problems with the iOS configuration. If anyone has experience with implementing this and can provide assistance, please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.